# changing JSON format

Tags: java, json, spring, web-services

With spring i create a this webservice

```
@POST
    @Path("/get_user_info")
    @Consumes({"application/json"})
    @Produces({"application/json"})
    public List<GetUserInfoResponse> get_User_Info(GetUserInfoRequest request) throws Exception;
```

This return me a list of `GetUserInfoResponse`  like this

[image]

Question : Is it possible to get a JSON like this ???? :

[image]

Class : GetUserInfoResponse

```
package com.audaxis.compiere.ws.bean.response;

//Same imports

@XmlRootElement(name="infos")
@XmlType(propOrder={"key", "values"})
public class GetUserInfoResponse {

    private int key;
    private List<GetUserInfo> values;

   //Same Constructor
   //Same getters && setters
}
```

Class : GetUserInfo

```
   package com.audaxis.compiere.ws.bean;
    //Same imports

    @XmlRootElement(name="values")
    @XmlType(propOrder={"columnName", "old_value", "new_value", "status", "motif"})
    public class GetUserInfo {

        private String columnName;
        private String old_value;
        private String new_value;
        private String status;
        private String motif;

//Same Constructor
//Same getters && setters

 }
```

And This is my program :

```
methode(){
    List<GetUserInfoResponse> responses = new ArrayList<GetUserInfoResponse>();
    while(rs.next()){
    GetUserInfoResponse response = new GetUserInfoResponse();
      for (X_Z_WS_Column column : columns) {
        GetUserInfo info = new GetUserInfo();
        //setinfo
        infos.add(info);
    }
    response.setValues(infos);
    responses.add(response);
   }
   return responses
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the basic java code to make json object and populate it.

```
import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;

public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
        obj.put("key", "city");

        JSONArray list = new JSONArray();
        list.add("Delhi");
        list.add("Mumbai");
        list.add("Bangalore");
        obj.put("value", list);

        System.out.print(obj);

    }

}
```

If you have any doubts about the format you are welcome to ask.
Output is:

{"value":["Delhi","Mumbai","Bangalore"],"key":"city"}

Comment: i dont create json like this, i instance bean above an the lib jackson i think translate bean to json

Comment: Can you post your whole program, I am not getting you?

Comment: What is the value of columns in this line? " for (X_Z_WS_Column column : columns) ". Where are you poplating the object?

Comment: this return column that contain values (every column make a value)

Comment: Then you can just remove the "infos column" wherever you are populating the columns.